# iPhone app architecture with tab bars

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that uses a tab bar controller. It has five tabs.

I need to base each tab on a UINavigationController. Do I require another view controller inside the nav controller, or is it valid to have a UINavigationController controlling a regular view?

(I'm guessing the latter but I'm really hitting a wall today getting it to work .. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UINavigationController is created by setting a rootViewController inside it.

```
- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
```

That root view controller will control the view.

In your tab bar controller, you can add the UINavigationController.

Answer (score 1):

Drag "Navigation Controller" icon to "Tab Bar Controller" in Interface Builder.
You will be able to use UINavigationController with UITabBarController.

In addition, if you drag "Table View Controller" to  "View Controller" inside the "Navigation Controller", they are exchanged and you can use UINavigationController + UITableView + UITabBarController.